# How can I expand this picture to cover the width of my page?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

[link](http://www.paulvanesch.com/)

Everything should be up to 720 px resolution.

I basically like my images in a slideshow to be until the end.
I put a picture more clearly understand what I mean.

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow" style="background: #F0F0F0;">
<div class="sub-menu" style="color: #ababab; font-family: myFirstFont; font-size: 12pt; float: left; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 2%;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png" alt="">Highlights from previous purchases</div>
        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

        <li style="display: list-item;">
    <img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/imag_home-1.png" alt="photo1"></li>

        <li>//same code HTML</li>
        <li>//same code HTML</li>
        <li>//same code HTML</li>
            //....
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to use this **CSS code** but not working:

```
@media (max-width: 720px){
    #slideshow li img{width:100%;}
}
```

Can you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want the image to maintain the same [aspect ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image))?

Comment: `#slideshow li img{width:100%;}` works fine, you have included a large transparent part as part of your image. You will also want to remove the `height` on `#slideshow ul li`

Comment: http://i65.tinypic.com/rt22l5.jpg I removed the code that you say and look how it looks now ... all is not well

Comment: Because your images contain large transparent areas - http://i.imgur.com/ecA20WO.png so it is scaling the images up. You would need to remove these transparent parts from the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size: cover` is what you need.  There is a good article here on scaling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images

Try this...

**[html](/questions/tagged/html)**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="sub-menu"><img src="/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/logo-arrow.png" alt="">Highlights from previous purchases</div>
        <ul>
            <li id="image1">&nbsp;</li>
            <li id="image2">//same code HTML</li>
            <li id="image3">//same code HTML</li>
            <li id="image4">//same code HTML</li>
            //....
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[css](/questions/tagged/css)**

```css
ul {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
ul > li {
    display: list-item;
}
#slideshow {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}
#slideshow > .submenu {
    color: #ababab;
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    font-size: 12pt;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.image1 {
    height: 200px; /* The height of the image */
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/images/imag_home-1.png') no-repeat 50% 50% fixed;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```